# MySQL replication between VPS and shared host

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a VPS where I have ssh access and shared host with CPanel. Both have MySQL.

I need to create a master/slave setup among the two server.
As per this tutorial: [How To Set Up Database Replication In MySQL](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication), I will need to modify the `my.conf` file.

Is it possible to achieve this with the following permissions on both the servers?

- VPS

  I have root access with ssh login where I can modify `/etc/my.conf` file.
- Shared host

  Cpanel with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

if you have MySQL root access on the shared host, there is a change that it works, just make sure that you:

- Use the VPS as master
- Enable the shared host ip to connect on vps host
- run a `SELECT @@server_id` on shared host and set the vps to use a different one.
- follow the steps described on tutorial
- run the `CHANGE MASTER TO` on SQL tab on PhpMyAdmin

Comment: gr8 thanks for reply, as per point 2 in my shared host i have access to phpmyadmin and cpanel.

Comment: try to create the replication user via cpanel